# Rolling Mean with Plyr

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to calculate a rolling mean using plyr.  The data is at the industry-country-year, with repeated observations for each industry-country.  The data is unbalanced, but most industry-countries have approximately 15 observations.

For example the data looks like this:

```
country       ISIC      Year      Value
Algeria        1        1990       400
Algeria        1        1991       450
Algeria        1        1992       460
Algeria        2        1990       450
Algeria        2        1991       500
Algeria        2        1992       450
Argentina      1        1990       400
Argentina      1        1991       450
Argentina      1        1992       460
Argentina      2        1990       450
Argentina      2        1991       500
Argentina      2        1992       450
.              .        .          .
.              .        .          .
```

If I subset the data to a specific industry and country I am able to calculate the rolling mean like this

```
rollmean(subdata$Value, 3)
```

However, I've been unable to get it to work with plyr, so as to calculate the rolling mean for each industry-country group.
I've tried:

```
roll <- ddply(data, .(country, ISIC), summarize, rollmean(data$Value, 3))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a rolling mean necessarily shortens the data which part of why you get the error.

```
ddply(dat, .(country, ISIC), function(df) data.frame(country=unique(df$country),                  
                                                     ISIC=unique(df$ISIC),
                                                     rolled=rollmean(df$Value, 3)))
    country ISIC   rolled
1   Algeria    1 436.6667
2   Algeria    2 466.6667
3 Argentina    1 436.6667
4 Argentina    2 466.6667
```

However, if you're doing a rolling mean on 3 samples and your data only has 3 samples, you're just calculating the mean:

```
ddply(dat, .(country, ISIC), summarise, mean(Value))

    country ISIC      ..1
1   Algeria    1 436.6667
2   Algeria    2 466.6667
3 Argentina    1 436.6667
4 Argentina    2 466.6667
```

UPDATED FOR COMMENTS:

To return the dates you can use the `na.pad` argument to `rollmean`:

```
ddply(dat, .(country, ISIC), function(df) {df$rolled <- rollmean(df$Value, 3, na.pad=TRUE); return(df)})
```

Comment: I'm still getting the following error: Error: k <= n is not TRUE.  Could this be because some of my industry-country groups have less than 3 observations?

Comment: Thats because you have some samples with less than 3 results:  `rollmean(1:5, 6)` gives the same error!

Comment: I dropped all of the groups that had less than 3 observations and now the code is working.  But how do I merge the new rolling mean with the original dataset?  When I try data$rollingmean <- ddply.... It gives me an error that the length of the two data sets are not the same.  I think maybe the confusion came from my example, where I only included 3 observations - most groups actually have 15 observations, so I need a way for the ddply output to still have the year information so that I can merge the rolling mean.  Any advice?